# How can I create multiple windows in winui 3.0?

Tags: c++, winui-3

I would like to have a button that creates another window. I'm building off the template app you get in VS2019 Preview So far, I've created a new control BlankWindow, just the default one. I can see that in App::OnLaunched, a window is created with:

```
window = make<MainWindow>();
window.Activate();
```

So in my MainWindow.xaml.cs in my button click method, I put:

```
Window bWindow= make<BlankWindow>();
bWindow.Activate();
```

That doesn't build, I check the BlankWindow.idl file and see that BlankWindow inherits from Controls and not Windows, so I change it. Now it builds, but when I click the button in the MainWindow, I see the window flicker open and instantly close. What's going on?

Comment: That limitation should be removed with the [WindowsAppSDK release 1.0.1](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/discussions/2291).

Answer (score 0):

Work on multi-window applications is ongoing. It's available as a Preview feature.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/#preview-features

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution to this problem in the definition of the [Window Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.window?view=winui-3.0) for the Windows UI Library (WinUI) under the subtitle "Create a new Window on a new thread". To put the section in context it would help to read the entire webpage. It's not that long.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We were able to include xaml.h for the target subwindow and display the window using the make template function.
Note that the types held in the member variables and the types specified to the make template function are different.

(I am using the translation at DeepL, so the text may be slightly incorrect.)

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "MainWindow.xaml.h"
#if __has_include("MainWindow.g.cpp")
#include "MainWindow.g.cpp"
#include "Window_Sub.xaml.h"
#endif
```

```
winrt::App1::Window_Sub _subWindow{ nullptr };
void MainWindow::ShowSubWindowButton_Clicked(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& e)
{  
    if (_subWindow == nullptr) {
        _subWindow = make<App1::implementation::Window_Sub>();
        _subWindow.Closed([](winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::WindowEventArgs const& e){
            _subWindow = nullptr;
        });
    }
    _subWindow.Activate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The support to multi-windows on the same thread was consistently introduced in Windows App SDK v1.1 (jun-2022). Here the [Changelog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/stable-channel#version-11-1).